# django rest framework - error on basic authentication

Tags: android, authentication, django-rest-framework, basic-authentication

I want to implement the most Basic Authentication in my django-rest-framework app, and I keep on getting a {"detail":"Invalid username/password."} response (sometimes 401 and sometimes 403).

Here is my UserViewSet code:

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
               mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
               mixins.ListModelMixin,
               viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
```

In the settings.py I don't have anything about authentication, just the default stuff.

my android code:

```
getUsers = new HttpGet("http://10.100.102.10:8000/users/");
String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("testingUser:123".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
getUsers.setHeader("Authorization", basicAuth);

// executing the request
response = httpClient.execute((HttpUriRequest) request);
result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

The user does exist in the Database - as you can see in the screen shot.

I am adding a screen shot of the json I am getting from the http://10.100.102.10:8000/users/ url in the browser, (after I removed the permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )) - meaning everyone can acces).

[image]

**This is the UserSerializer:**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', )

        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                first_name = validated_data['first_name'],
                last_name = validated_data['last_name'],
                username = validated_data['username'],
                password = validated_data['password'],
            )
            return user
```

What is wrong with my code? any reason this doesn't work?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the authentication details as a part of Authorization Header which is Token Authentication. The default authentication scheme for Django Rest Framework is Session Authentication. You need to add TokenAuthentication to 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' in your settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ),
 }
```